# open a port owned by root on linux?

Tags: linux, macos, root, kill

I am currently working with docker, the image of my container is on port 49161, however, the port was occupied by another process. So I killed this process by doing sudo kill PID in order to free the port. Nevertheless, now the port seems to be occupied by a PID belonging to the root. Is it possible to free this port (49161) ?

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
findmydev 267 root    4u  IPv6 0xcf3f933fd8e68451      0t0  TCP [fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe00:1122]:49161->[fe80:4::aede:48ff:fe33:4455]:49169 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: You can still kill the process it does not matter where is the owner as long as you have root privilege

Comment: But when i do  " sudo kill PID (of the user named root) " it doesn’t work. What can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
 pgrep -u root [processID]
```